# Catch Hibernate exceptions in Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I'm trying to build a small REST service using Quarkus. I'm using Hibernate and a PostgreSQL database. It works pretty well in all good cases. But when there are Hibernate exceptions like `ConstraintViolationException` I'm not able to catch them in a normal way. The exceptions are wrapped with to other exception `ArcUndeclaredThrowableException` and `RollbackException`. So the exceptions can just be catched by using

```
catch (ArcUndeclaredThrowableException e) {
...
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Dependent
public class UserRepository {

    @Transactional
    public void createUser(User user) {
        getEntityManager().persist(user); //<- the constraint violation happens at commit, so when transaction will be closed
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
    @Override
    public Response createUser(@Valid CreateUserDTO createUserDTO, UriInfo uriInfo) {
        ...
        try {
            userRepository.createUser(user);
        } catch (ArcUndeclaredThrowableException e) { //<- here the hibernate exception should be catchable
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Because of this issue it's also not possible to add an `ExceptionMapper` for HibernateExceptions.
Does anybody had similar problems or is there a general problem with my code? I'm using Java11.

Comment: In this case, I usually wrap exception into some unified-custom exceptions ex: (DataException or Service Exception), then I create one or two mappers for that.

Comment: @iabughosh Can you give me an example for this? I want to distinguish between different Exceptions because in my case the `ConstraintException` is a business case and should respond with a different status code than all others exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(user);
        getEntityManager().flush();
} catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    throw new MyCustomException(e);
}
```

And create Exception mapper for MyCustomException.

Answer (score 0):

You can flush the Hibernate session this should triggers exceptions like `ConstraintViolationException` without commiting the transaction.

In your case this should be something like

```
@Dependent
public class UserRepository {

    @Transactional
    public void createUser(User user) {
        getEntityManager().persist(user);
        getEntityManager().flush();// should triger ConstraintViolationException
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also thought about the `flush`. The problem with this is you can't combine several calls into one transaction, because they will flush during execution.

Comment: Maybe I don't undesrtand what you means, but as `flush` didn't commit I don't understand what is your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and found a workaround.
The problem, as far as I can understand is, that Arc (the cdi implemtation of quarkus) sometimes needs to generate classes.

Checked exceptions (like javax.transaction.RollbackExcpetion) need to be somehow propegated to the user. The checked Exception is therefore wrapped inside the ArcUndeclaredThrowableException. This only needs to be done however if you do not explicitly handle the exception.

For example, you can just declare the exception:

```
@Dependent
public class UserRepository {

    @Transactional
    public void createUser(User user) throws RollbackException{
        getEntityManager().persist(user);
    }
}
```

In your Resource, you can then catch the RollbackException

```
@Override
public Response createUser(@Valid CreateUserDTO createUserDTO, UriInfo uriInfo) {
    ...
    try {
        userRepository.createUser(user);
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import jakarta.transaction.RollbackException
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider

@Provider
@Singleton
open class RollbackExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<RollbackException> {
    
    override fun toResponse(exception: RollbackException): Response {
        if (exception.cause is TheHibernateExceptionWhatYouNeedToHandleWithException) {
            // TODO handle what you need
            return
        }

        // Other If condition you want

        throw exception
    }
}
```

I'm using Kotlin on back-end but you can also use Java.